# Creating vectors and matrices on Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, arrays, jupyter-notebook

I'm having a challenge creating vectors and matrices in jupyter notebook after importing numpy. When I try printing the array, an error pops up stating that 'variable name is not defined'. Thanks guys.

[image]

Comment: 1- Please do not post images of code (especially if low quality), 2- you forgot to run the first two cells of the notebook

Comment: I just did that, the code is working perfectly. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run cells with code importing numpy and initializing an array. Click on the first cell and then hit Shift+Enter (or click the Run button) on every cell (focus switches automatically to next cell).

Comment: I just did that, the code is working perfectly. Thanks alot.